# thinking sphinx fails configuring development config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have installed thinking sphinx and after running rake ts:index , it fails to configure the development file. The file is created, but it is empty.

```
Generating configuration to /Users/lexi87/dating/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:64:in `type_from_database'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:17:in `type'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute.rb:4:in `type'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:30:in `sphinx_type'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:18:in `collection_type'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:107:in `block in prepare_for_render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:104:in `prepare_for_render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:61:in `render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `block in render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `collect'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/index.rb:48:in `render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:39:in `block in render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:39:in `collect'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:39:in `render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:81:in `render'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:87:in `block in render_to_file'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:87:in `render_to_file'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:4:in `configure'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:31:in `index'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:index
```

I am not sure if this is related to my user_index.rb under the indices folder.

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do
  # fields
  indexes content
  indexes user.name, :as => :user, :sortable => true

# attributes
  has user_id, created_at, updated_at, ethnicity, religion

end
```

Here's my thinking_sphinx.yml file:

```
development:
  mysql41: 9312
test:
  mysql41: 9313
production:
  mysql41: 9312
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which model you are trying to index?, if its User, then first try having the line "indexes content" in your User model and rake ts:index

Comment: The user model is what I need it for.

Comment: Try this and tell me the output , class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  define_index do
    indexes content
  end  end

Comment: I get a undefined method `define_index' , but define index was removed in the new version and relocated to /indices. I have it in my user_index.rb file. The code is above

Comment: ok wait, let me quickly go through the new documentation

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9972/beck03076

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error, while not clear, is due to one of your attribute references being not quite correct... If you're indexing the User model, then I'm guessing there isn't an association on it called `user` - so, `user_id` should just be `id`, and `user.name` should just be `name`:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do
  # fields
  indexes content
  indexes name, :as => :user, :sortable => true

  # attributes
  has id, created_at, updated_at, ethnicity, religion
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the "has id". Such a easy fix I look over.